# How does handsontable's cellProperties work?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

In handsontable when I want to set row to readonly

```
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
  var cellProperties = {};
  if (row === 1) {
    cellProperties.readOnly = true;
  }
  return cellProperties;
}
```

and when setting column

```
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
  var cellProperties = {};
  if (prop === 'id') {
    cellProperties.readOnly = true;
  }
  return cellProperties;
}
```

These works well but how does JS work? because I don't see any assignment or calling any function.

Answer (score -1):

Cell properties are used to set how the cell are going to be renderer, actually in your case you are updating cellProperties according to your needs, so when the cell gets rendered is using your updated configuration.

Cheers.